# How to convert a map to a consumer of a map in java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, consumer

I have a method A that takes (Consumer<Map<String, List>>) as a method parameter.

```
 public void myMethodA(Consumer<Map<String,List<String>>> someMap) {
```

However, my method B which calls method A has a Hashmap with it:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = Collections.singletonMap("a1", Arrays.asList("b"));
```

How can I pass the variable myMap to method A?
I tried:

```
myMethodA((Consumer<Map<String,List<String>>>) myMap);
```

but I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$SingletonMap incompatible with java.util.function.Consumer
```

Comment: you don't need a map to call `myMethodA`, you need a callable that will use a map to do something with. You can't pass a map to `myMethodA` because that is not what myMethodA is here for

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you expect the `Consumer` to do?

Comment: The singleton Map ha K,V whereas the map you have as the argument has "a Key for each List" not each member of the List. A List has E elements the V value but no K corresponding E.

Answer (score -1):

A consumer is a function<sup>1</sup>. Functions aren't maps. Functions are.. functions - the only thing you can do with them, is invoke the function. Specifically, a consumer is a function that takes in an object of type T, and returns `void` (nothing).

Thus, `Consumer<Map<String,List<String>>> someMap` is completely wrong. It's like calling you (Tiya) a sandwich, because you can eat sandwiches. You're not a sandwich at all, you can consume sandwiches though.

The only difference between `a` and `b` in:

```
public void a(Map<String, List<String>> map) { ... }

Consumer<Map<String, List<String>> b = map -> ....;
```

is that one is a method and can be used in contexts where method invocations are required, and the other is a variable. They do the same thing. In fact, I can turn the `a` method into a function:

```
Consumer<Map<String, List<String>> b = this::a;
```

which works fine.

Thus, there is no way to do what you want, for the same reason it makes absolutely no sense to do this:

Joe: Hey, I made a sandwich. Can you find me somebody that can eat sandwiches?

Tiya: Sure! Here, have this sandwich *I* made.

Joe: What the.... That's a sandwich. I wanted a thing that can eat sandwiches!

1. In java, things have to be either objects (as in, the expression has a 'reference type') or primitives (as in, the expression has a 'primitive type'). Functions are simply reference types where the type is a so-called functional interface: An interface that defines precisely 1 method. At that point, 'an object whose only externally callable anything is this one precisely defined function' and 'a function' become pretty much the same thing. When I say "A consumer is a function", if that confuses you, then this footnote explains the full line of reasoning going on here.